# Django - ModelChoiceField <domain object>

Tags: django, django-forms

I use a `ModelChoiceField` but I have a problem with the display:

my form:

```
lsdom = Domin.objects.all()
dm1 = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        initial=0,
        queryset=lsdom,
        label="",
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={'size': 1,'id':'lsdom1'})
      )
```

My html:

```
{{ form.dm1|bootstrap }}
```

My class `Domin` have a name and a surname...

But in the list,  it display and not her name.

I try this : 
`lsdom = Domin.objects.all().values_list("name",flat=True)`
and the display is good but when I want validate the form, I have a error message. I think is not the good solution...

Thank you

Comment: For one, your field in the HTML doesn't correspond with the field in the model class. "But in the list, it display and not her name." - what does that mean?

Comment: I want in my list html, the values are the names of Domin. But I resolve this problem, I change method __str__ but now I have a problem with ascii è_é

Comment: ModelChoiceField by default displays the string representation of the model, that is, `Domin.__unicode__` or `Domin.__str__`

Comment: Davide.R I change __str__ but I have a problem with accents, how resolves it ? The accents are not supported

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3? Exactly what code do you have in the `__str__` method?